# How can I match the impedance in the distributed transmission line model?

Tags: analog, simulation, impedance-matching, cadence

I'm trying to do impedance matching for an inverter transmitting signal through a transmission line in Cadence. The transmission line is modelled as a number of RLC elements(\$R_{TL}=0.1\Omega\$,\$L_{TL}=250nH, C_{TL}=100pF, and N = 10\$) connected in series (as shown below).

[image]

The model approximately represents 1 meter of RG-58 coaxial cable (with resistance of \$ 50\Omega\$). I suppose the idea is to keep the output impedance, the impedance of the transmission line, and the impedance of the load equal. So I put a \$ 50\Omega\$ termination resistor at the end of the transmission line, and put a \$ 40\Omega\$ resistor between the inverter and the transmission line since the output impedance of the inverter is approximately \$ 10\Omega\$（measured by simulation).

However, the waveform at output node does not improve a lot after impedance matching. The top one is the Output before impedance matching, and the bottom one is after impedance matching. I'm wondering if the approach is correct and why the waveform still has glitches. I put part of the schematic at the end(there are 10 singleRLC modules in the middle), if that helps.
[image: Output before impedance matching]

[image: Output after impedance matching]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your screenshot, you're simulating a cable using discrete 10cm segments. For that model to be accurate, your rise time must be much longer (order of magnitude) than the time for your signal to propagate 10 cm, which is about 0.5 ns.  How fast do your transistors switch?

My guess is a few nanoseconds at most, since for a real piece of RG-58 if you put a 50 ohm terminating resistor and measure the output of a square wave generator you'll get a relatively clean edge with minimal reflection.

Comment: Yes. I do have a very short rising time (only 1 ps). But the frequency is only 1kHz. Can you explain why the rising time has to be much longer?

Comment: I tried with rising time being 50ns. It did get much more better. So curious why is this. Why the rising time has to be longer than the propagation time?

Comment: @GeorgeGuo The rise time sets the bandwidth of each pulse. A picosecond pulse has a bandwidth of ~350 of GHz. Setting the repetition rate of your 350 GHz pulse to 1 KHz means you have 1000 350 GHz pulses per second. Each one is still 350 GHz.

Comment: @GeorgeGuo You're trying to simulate a continuous line with discrete elements, so those elements need to be small relative to the edges on the line. Since your edges are very short compared to the elements making up the line, they see 10 individual RLC filters rather than a continuous transmission line.

Answer (score 1):

The signal applied has a rate-of-change that is high (because it is a square wave rather than a trapezoid or, best of all, sine).  A finite round-trip-time still exists with 1m of transmission line.  Until the signal settles down (an expiration of 2 or 3 RTT's) we would expect to see that ringing, because to start off with the signal is underdamped - we are trying to drive a transient, a step change, into the transmission line - until that transient meets it's own reflection coming back from the other end, we will see a typical signal as your image displays.  But, note how much better it is when you terminate everything properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So am I doing the termination in the right way? Or is it possible that the impedance of the transmission line is not 50 so the waveform after termination is still bad?

Comment: I hesitate to say "Yes", because, really, the result is the answer.  But you are following the principles.  It is very true that often 75 ohm coax gets mislabelled as 50 ohm - so perhaps you should explore that possibility also.